# Get networking restrictions details of Function App

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to get the details of the Azure function app specifically the inbound traffic restrictions (inbound IPs, Access restriction, App assigned address, Private endpoints). I can see these under -

[image]

```
from azure.mgmt.web import WebSiteManagementClient as web_client
mgmt_client_old = web_client(credentials, subscription_id)
func = mgmt_client.web_apps.get(resource_group_name=resource_group, name=app_name).as_dict()
pprint(func)
```

I have tried the above code which tells me about the outbound ip addresses and gives me other details but does not give any insights into the inbound IPs, Access restriction, App assigned address, Private endpoints. I have even tried - func = `mgmt_client.web_apps.get_configuration(resource_group_name=resource_group, name=app_name).as_dict()` but even that does not provide me with the details.

Comment: `nslookup <app-name>.azurewebsites.net` - run the following command in a local terminal to find the inbound IP of your azure function app!

Comment: I am trying to find out about IP restrictions and what IPs are allowed I know the IP address of my Azure function app.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to find out about IP restrictions and what IPs are allowed

***Networking restrictions are dependent on the Hosting plans of Azure Functions as you can see them below:***

[image]

- You can use Private Endpoint for your functions hosted in the [Premium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan) and [App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dedicated-plan) plans.
- IP restrictions work with all function-hosting options.
- Outbound IP restrictions are available in a Premium plan, App Service plan, or App Service Environment. You can configure outbound restrictions for the virtual network where your App Service Environment is deployed.
- When you integrate a ***function app*** in a Premium plan or an App Service plan with a virtual network, the app can still make outbound calls to the internet by default. By integrating your function app with a VNet with Route All enabled, you force all outbound traffic to be sent into your virtual network, where network security group rules can be used to restrict traffic.

For more detailed information on azure functions networking restrictions and options, please refer this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options).